# How to send messages to a window

Tags: gtk, glib, mate-terminal

I've got a hung window "Set Title" in Ubuntu mate-terminal that doesn't react to input. I can move the window, but it doesn't render properly (with text box and "Ok" button), nor can I click the window icon on the top left. I can click the [x] on the top right, but nothing happens for a few seconds until I get a dialog asking whether I want to kill the unresponsive application. I don't want that since it'll terminate all my mate-terminal instances which would make me very sad.

I can still spawn new terminals. Is it possible to send that window a message (WM_CLOSE?) to just go away as if the ESC key had been pressed, and if so, how (I know xprop, but that's just for displaying window properties)? Bonus points if I can do that on the command line, but compiling a simply C program would be ok too.

Thanks.

Comment: What does this Set Title program do?

Comment: Did the program come with the standard installation, or did you install it from some repository?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The "Set Title" is a modal window for mate-terminal to set the title of a terminal tab. It is invoked by right-click on the tab and select "Set Title...".

Comment: @AdminBee This is mate-terminal, which came from the repository for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the ✗ button sends the close message. But your process is not responding.  Probably something went wrong somewhere. You can click close then the minimise button, and hope that it eventually responds.

Maybe it opened a dialog window, that you have ignored (on another screen, or under a window).

Maybe the program has a bug, that you can't get around, and have to kill it.